# What is the Simplest Way to Solve a System of Functions

Tags: functions

In class we are learning about solving function systems. I have been given multiple way to solve these yet I still do not understand which one I would use in real life.
Please help me choose one of the three.
Finding the Intersection on a Graph.
Substitution
Elimination

Comment: Do you think you can add some detail to your question?

Comment: May be giving an example might help people answer.

Comment: Are you talking about [systems of equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) or finding the roots of an equation? At any case, can you tell more about your math level or knowledge. "Simplest" is relative, some cases may require analytical answers, others a simple numeric computation suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real life, using a computer program is best unless the problem is very simple. Otherwise:

Finding the intersection on a graph is best if you don't need to be super accurate, as long as you can graph it.

Elimination tends to be faster than substitution for me, as there are not as many fractions until the end. Otherwise, they are pretty similar.